# How do i return a Eigen::Matrix from a method such it do not copy the data when returning

Tags: eigen

I have:

```
Eigen::MatrixXf load_from_gpu()
{
    Eigen::MatrixXf mat(m_rows,m_cols);
    clEnqueueReadBuffer(m_manager->m_gpu_queue_loader, m_buffer, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float)*numel(), mat.data(), 0, NULL, NULL); 
    return mat; 
}
```

I belive that when i call this method the data is stored to one mat and then copyed to mat2 : `Eigen::MatrixXf mat2 = load_from_gpu();`

Is it possible to make it write the data into the matrix which is the rhs of the function call of `load_from_gpu()`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your compiler should be able to do this for you, using the common [Return Value Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) method. Basically what this does, is that the compiler rewrites `load_from_gpu` to take a pointer to an `Eigen::MatrixXf` as a parameter, and fill that matrix directly.

Note that it can only do this because it can see that `mat` will always be the return value, if there are several matrices in the methods and one gets returned based on some condition, the compiler doesn't know which one to replace with the hidden pointer parameter. In this case you have to resort to doing it manually, like in alrikai's answer.

To enable the optimization you have to compile with `-O2` with GCC.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used Eigen much, but can't you pass your Matrix as a reference parameter and assign it in `load_from_gpu()`? That is,

```
void load_from_gpu(Eigen::MatrixXf& mat)
{
    clEnqueueReadBuffer(m_manager->m_gpu_queue_loader, m_buffer, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float)*numel(), mat.data(), 0, NULL, NULL);
}
```

Comment: That is my alternative if i cant get the other stuff working.

Comment: I would like it to be returned by the function and not as a argument.

Comment: Ah so you want to allocate your temporary MatrixXf on the heap and return a pointer to it? To be honest I would consider the reference parameter option to be better one stylistically